# Build angular app with with angular cli

Tags: angular, angular-cli, ngx-translate

I'm facing a problem with the build of my angular 5 app. I'm using angular cli and ngx-translate.

I build my application with `ng build --base-href /my/folder/ --deploy-url /my/folder/`. The Js files are well served from `http://www.example.org/my/folder/` but all my assets from `http://www.example.org/assets/i18n` in place of `http://www.example.org/my/folder/assets/i18n`.

Someone can help me ?

Thanks

Comment: I think you can just change the configuration in the .angular-cli.json file, change `"outDir": "dist",` to whatever you like: `"outDir": "my/folder",` for example

Comment: I've tried but it seems to have no effects

Comment: This is a known issue: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/6730 that seems to be fixed on 13 Dec 2017 What's your angular-cli version ? You need to have a version >= 1.6.1

Comment: 1.6.5 but I saw that the last version is 1.7.2. I'll try to update and see what append.

Comment: No change, still looking for my json translate file in root of my server in place of in subfolder.

Comment: Is it only your ngx-translate assets ? In my personal experience, I suffered from many problems with ngx-translate, and I won't use it for any new project. If you are in an early stage of the application, please consider using the built-in internationalization system in Angular.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution, I had to add this in my app.module.ts file :
`export function HttpLoaderFactory(httpClient: HttpClient) {
    return new TranslateHttpLoader(httpClient, "./assets/i18n/", ".json");
}`

Hope it helps!